# java interface to swagger or opanapi 3.0.0 YAML

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

Is there any way to generate `swagger 2.0` or `openapi 3.0.0` YAML/json file from my existing interface.

I have googled a lot but couldn't find it. Please help

Answer (score 0):

What I do is reverse engineer the java code into a modelling tool MagicDraw, and then have a report generator template that generates the YAML.